# ¿Por qué CSS no está ejecutando Flexbox a un div?

Tags: html, css

Básicamente quiero llevar el div en el que está "Contact" a la derecha del todo, mientras dejo el otro div (que contiene "About", "products" y "Our team") a la izquierda. Para esto he hecho lo siguiente:

```
   <nav>
    <div class="container3">
      <p>About</p>
      <p>Produts</p>
      <p>Our Team</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container1">
      <p>Contact</p>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Y en css:

```css
nav {
    display: flex;

}
.container1{
    justify-items: flex-end;
}
```

Pero no hace nada. También he probado con justify-content y tampoco. El caso es que si aplico justify en el nav, si ejecuta bien. Pero el problema es que solo quiero aplicar justify al segundo div. El primero quiero que se quede dónde esté.

Comment: te paso un link de como funciona flex, de seguro te servirá https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/   todo lo que está a la izquierda son estilos para el contenedor, lo de la derecha para los items

Comment: También puedes probar con `flex-direction: row-reverse`

Answer (score 2):

Quizás te sirva este ejemplo si lo que necesitas es formar dos columnas alineadas a la izquierda y derecha respectivamente.

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="container3">
      <p>About</p>
      <p>Produts</p>
      <p>Our Team</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container1">
      <p>Contact</p>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Gracias. Entonces por lo que veo es que ese tipo de propiedades sólo sirve para el elemento padre y no funcionan si se aplican a los elementos de dentro, no?

Comment: mas bien, en flex no puedes decir que unos hijos van a la izquierda y otros a la derecha, así no funciona

Comment: Si puedes utilizarlos pero requiere más reglas css para lograrlo.

Answer (score 0):

el problema es el siguiente :

1) es `justify-content` y no `justify-items`

2)  estas propriedades se las tenes que insertar al container y no al hijo, asi el contenedor alinea su contenido en base a tus necesidades.

tu codigo css tendria que quedar asi :

```
nav{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end; //flex-start || flex-end || space-around ... 
}
```

en caso contrario podrias usar la propriedad para el hijo : `align-self:`

y quedaria asi :

```
nav{
   display: flex;
}
.container1{
     align-self: flex-end; // flex-start | center... ecc
}
```

espero que te sea de ayuda, exitos